# how to fill my table in sql server automatic

Tags: sql, sql-server

hi i have table in `sql server` and i want to make lot's of data automatically 
for testing . how can i do that

Comment: Use SQL commands to insert data. I think the question is too broad and it is hard to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you wan to to fill just one table? without FK ?

you can try this:
https://www.mockaroo.com/

Comment: A data generator that can't handle foreign keys is pretty much useless for any serious real-life database

Comment: the question mentioned only a table.
but i think you're rigth.

Comment: thanks that's exactly what i need

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the type of data you need, but if it's just a question of volume, you could do something like:

```
declare @i int
set @i = 0
while @i < 100000
begin
    insert into [user](first_name, last_name)
    values ('FirstName' + cast(i as nvarchar(20), 'LastName' + cast(i as nvarchar(20)))
    set @i = @i + 1
end
```